# Creating series of instagram videos with the same templates in premieme pro

Tags: premiere, video-editor, workflow

I am a content provider and have an instagram account with 86K followers. I need to upload at least 4 videos everyday. Until now, I created about 300 videos. All of them have been edited in just one premiere project. My problem is that the more videos that I add to this project, the slower it gets, logarithmically.

One solution is to create each video in its own project. While this works from the point of performance, it poses a new problem in reusing common resources across projects.

So, my question is how do people manage large numbers of similar videos for social media?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a master template project which is setup with all of your folder hierarchies and the common assets you need to access for the edits.

You could save this project as "Master Project Template", and save it within it's own folder with all of the assets, or if the common assets you access take up a lot of disk space, you may want to have two folders- 1.) Master Project File, 2.) Assets. You'll want a 3rd folder where you have all of your unique project specific assets; 3.)Instagram Videos, with subfolders for each day, using a simple naming convention YYMMDD.

Regardless of whether it's one or two folders; to make sure you don't have issues linking project assets down the road if you migrate to a new system or drive; I'd set them up on a drive so they are one level above the root directory for that drive:

D:\Instagram Videos\Master Project Template\Master Project Template.prproj
D:\Instagram Videos\Master Project Assets\ (Here you can host all of your common assets in one folder or organized into multiple folders. I personally recommend if using multiple folders, to name your Premiere Pro Bins identically to the naming convention and folder structure so what's on the drive in your assets folder, can be found in the exact corresponding system folder).

Now that you've set up a "Master Project Template", you'll want to make your first "Project".

Copy the Master Project Folder, and paste it into the same directory. When prompted by Windows, select create a 2nd copy. Now you'll have a 2nd Copy with "copy(1)" added to the end of the folder name.

Now right click the "copy" and rename the folder.

*Just my recommendation,* but create a folder naming scheme either using a simple three or four digit numeric prefix "0001 - Instagram Videos", or use YYMMDD (Not DDMMYY), so you can sort the list of project folders by date correctly: "181013 - Instagram Videos".

You now have a new project folder which regardless if your assets are located in the master project folder, or in a sidecar folder (same root directory), which you can open and create your videos from.

You can choose how many videos per "master folder" you want to create, perhaps 1 folder per week, or month.

Final thought, for your master project "project", set up all of your timelines, including nested timelines, with all of your audio filters already applied, your adjustment layers already in place, etc, so you just have to drop your video assets in.

I would also recommend creating a simple TXT file in the master project folder named "README.txt" which you can write notes/add info on updates to the master project folder, such as adding assets, etc.

You'll want a 3rd folder in the root directory that contains your assets that are not common; organized likely by folder using a simple YYMMDD naming scheme. It would look like this:

D:\Instagram Videos\Online Assets\181013
D:\Instagram Videos\Online Assets\181014
D:\Instagram Videos\Online Assets\181015

This will keep everything organized, it will keep your Premiere Pro project file lightweight so you don't have performance issues, it will allow you to easily update the "Master" project file at any time, which for each time you copy for a new batch of videos, would thus include the new version with new added common assets.

Hope this helps.